# Proof of linear time-invariant system output

Tags: stochastic-processes, linear-transformations, solution-verification

I am trying to learn systems with stochastic inputs, especially deterministic systems.

$L[\cdot]$ represents a time-invariant system if $$ Y(t) =  L\{X(t) \} \implies  Y(t - t_0) =  L\{X(t - t_0) \}. $$

Now I was trying to understand the following proof for a linear time-invariant system, where I cannot get the starred step ($\delta(\cdot)$ is Dirac's delta):
\begin{align}
\begin{array}{lll}
Y(t) & = L\{X(t) \} & \textit{linear system}\\
& = L \{ \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} X(\tau) \delta(t - \tau) d\tau\} & \textit{Dirac representation}\\
& = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} L \{  X(\tau) \delta(t - \tau) d\tau\} & \textit{linearity}\\
& = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} X(\tau)  L \{  \delta(t - \tau) \}d\tau & \textit{linearity}\\
& = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} X(\tau)  h(t - \tau)d\tau & \textit{}\\
& = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} X(t - \tau)  h(\tau)d\tau & \textit{*****}
\end{array}
\end{align}
What is the relationship between the last step and time-invariance? Maybe it follows since in the second last step $h(t-\tau)$ is $0$  everywhere except $\tau = t$ then it has $X(\tau)$ next to itself, and in the last step $h(\tau) = 0$ when $\tau = 0$ so $X(t - \tau)$ becomes $X(t)$ again. Still, I cannot get where we use time-invariance.